# Creating a new type of section - Styling toc

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, titlesec, tocloft

I need to create a new style of section (like a chapter) BUT on the ToC should be styled as a Part.

Here's a Minimal Non Working Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{extbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%Style of Chapter
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\color{red}\bfseries\Huge}{Chapter \thechapter:\ }{0em}{}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{6pt}

%%To create the new section
\titleclass{\customchapter}[0]{top}
\newcounter{customchapter}
\renewcommand{\thecustomchapter}{\Alph{customchapter}}

%With the same style of chapter
\titleformat{\customchapter}
{\color{red}\bfseries\Huge}{Custom Chapter \thecustomchapter:\ }{0em}{}

\titlespacing{\customchapter}{0pt}{0pt}{6pt}

%%%%%Style on ToC%%%%%

%%PART%%
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries\color{green}} %Green style

%%Capitolo%%
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\color{red}}    %Style

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Default Chapter}
\chapter{Another Default Chapter}
\customchapter{Custom Chapter}That should start the counter from 0 (or A)
\end{document}
```

I've thinked to something like `\customchapter*{Custom Chapter}\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Custom Chapter \Alph{customchapter}: Custom Chapter}`, but in this way all the counter stuffs will be broken.

Let me know, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I’m not particularly keen in using the `titlesec`/`titletoc` packages (I’d say I’m rather dumb, actually), but, since 7 hours has elapsed without an answer being posted, I’ll try to write one.  As I said, I’m going to use `titletoc`, rather then `tocloft`.

The main problem, here, is that `\part` commands do *not* write to the `.toc` file an entry of the form `\numberline{...}...`, as `\chapter` commands do; this messes up the format of the ToC entry (re)defined with the `\titlecontents` command.  My workaround for this is a crude hack.

Indeed, the `newparttoc` option of the `titlesec` package is meant exactly to address this issue, but it’s only effective if the `\part` command is redefined, which we don’t want to do.

Here is my code (texts are quotations of Dante Alighieri’s *Inferno*, of course):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book} % I'm using 10-point size for this example
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % I prefer to stick to 7-bit ASCII
\usepackage[italian]{babel}   % I'm Italian too! (;-)
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%Style of Chapter
\titleformat{\chapter}
    [display]                           % shape
    {\color{red}\bfseries\Huge}         % format
    {\chaptertitlename~\thechapter:\ }  % label
    {0em}                               % sep
    {}                                  % before-code

\titlespacing{\chapter} % unstarred = indentfirst
    {0pt}{0pt}{6pt} % left- / before- / after-sep

%%To create the new section
\titleclass{\customchapter}{top}[\part]
\newcounter{customchapter}
\renewcommand*{\thecustomchapter}{\Alph{customchapter}}
\newcommand*{\customchaptername}{Capitolo jolly}

%With the same style of chapter
\titleformat{\customchapter}
    [display]                           % shape
    {\color{red}\bfseries\Huge}         % format
    {\customchaptername~\thecustomchapter:\ }  % label
    {0em}                               % sep
    {}                                  % before-code
    [\markboth{}]                       % after-code

\titlespacing{\customchapter}
    {0pt}{0pt}{6pt} % left- / before- / after-sep

\makeatletter
    \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{
        \def\toclevel@customchapter{0}
    }
\makeatother

%%%%%Style on ToC%%%%%

%% Part %%
% \renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries\color{green}} %Green style

% The toc line format for part must be tweaked in order to account for the 
% special format of the line contained in the ".toc" file:
\titlecontents{part}
    [0pt]   % left-indent should be zero
    {% above-code
        \medbreak % for example
        \large\bfseries
        \color{green}%
    }{% numbered-entry-format
        % never used, however a fallback definition is provided
        \contentslabel{0pc}% should be equal to left-indent, see above
    }{%numberless-entry-format
        % leave empty
    }{% page-format
        \hfill\contentspage
    }[% below-code
        \nobreak\medskip
    ]

%% Chapter %%
% \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\color{red}}    %Style
\titlecontents{chapter}
    [1.5em] % left-indent; change as you see fit
    {% above-code
        \color{red}%
    }{% numbered-entry-format
        \contentslabel{1.5em}% should be equal to left-indent, see above
    }{%numberless-entry-format
        \hspace*{1.5em}% same remark as preceding argument applies
    }{% page-format
        \hfill\contentspage
    }

%% Custom Chapter %%
\titlecontents{customchapter}
    [0pt]   % left-indent; change as you see fit
    {% above-code
        \medbreak % for example
        \large\bfseries
        \color{green}%
    }{% numbered-entry-format
        \def\numberline##1{##1\hspace{1em}}% >>> CRUDE HACK <<<
    }{%numberless-entry-format
        % leave empty
    }{% page-format
        \hfill\contentspage
    }



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Inferno}

\chapter{Prologo}
Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita mi ritrovai per una selva oscura, ch\'{e} 
la diritta via era smarrita.

\chapter{Dubbi di Dante}
Lo giorno se ne andava, e l'aere bruno toglieva gli animai che sono in terra 
dalle fatiche loro.

\customchapter{Il primo capitolo jolly}
Dovrebbe cominciare la numerazione da~<<A>>.

\chapter{Ingresso all'Inferno}
Per me si va nella citt\`{a} dolente, per me si va nell'etterno dolore, per me 
si va tra la perduta gente.
\section{Ignavi}
Non ragioniam di lor, ma guarda e passa.
\section{Caronte}
Ed ecco verso noi venir per nave un vecchio, bianco per antico pelo, gridando 
<<Guai a voi, anime prave!>>

\customchapter{Un altro capitolo jolly}
Deve essere numerato~<<B>>.

\chapter{Limbo}
Ruppemi l'alto sonno nella testa un greve truono, s\'{\i} ch'io mi riscossi,
come persona ch'\`{e} per forza desta.

\end{document}
```

## Addition

Modified code, as per OP’s request:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book} % I'm using 10-point size for this example
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % I prefer to stick to 7-bit ASCII
\usepackage[italian]{babel}   % I'm Italian too! (;-)
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%Style of Chapter
\titleformat{\chapter}
    [display]                           % shape
    {\color{red}\bfseries\Huge}         % format
    {\chaptertitlename~\thechapter:\ }  % label
    {0em}                               % sep
    {}                                  % before-code

\titlespacing{\chapter} % unstarred = indentfirst
    {0pt}{0pt}{6pt} % left- / before- / after-sep

%%To create the new section
\titleclass{\customchapter}{top}[\part]
\newcounter{customchapter}
\renewcommand*{\thecustomchapter}{\Alph{customchapter}}
\newcommand*{\customchaptername}{Capitolo jolly}

%With the same style of chapter
\titleformat{\customchapter}
    [display]                           % shape
    {\color{red}\bfseries\Huge}         % format
    {\customchaptername~\thecustomchapter:\ }  % label
    {0em}                               % sep
    {}                                  % before-code
    [\markboth{}]                       % after-code

\titlespacing{\customchapter}
    {0pt}{0pt}{6pt} % left- / before- / after-sep

\makeatletter
    \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{
        \def\toclevel@customchapter{0}
    }
\makeatother

%%%%%Style on ToC%%%%%

%% Part %%
% \renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries\color{green}} %Green style

% The toc line format for part must be tweaked in order to account for the 
% special format of the line contained in the ".toc" file:
\titlecontents{part}
    [0pt]   % left-indent should be zero
    {% above-code
        \medbreak % for example
        \large\bfseries
        \color{green}%
    }{% numbered-entry-format
        % never used, however a fallback definition is provided
        \partname~\contentslabel{0pc}% should be equal to left-indent, see above
    }{%numberless-entry-format
        \FormatPartToCLine % or just "\partname~", sparing one macro!
    }{% page-format
        \hfill\contentspage
    }[% below-code
        \nobreak\medskip
    ]
\newcommand*{\FormatPartToCLine}[1]{\partname~#1}

%% Chapter %%
% \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\color{red}}    %Style
\titlecontents{chapter}
    [1.5em] % left-indent; change as you see fit
    {% above-code
        \color{red}%
    }{% numbered-entry-format
        \contentslabel{1.5em}% should be equal to left-indent, see above
    }{%numberless-entry-format
        \hspace*{1.5em}% same remark as preceding argument applies
    }{% page-format
        \hfill\contentspage
    }

%% Custom Chapter %%
\titlecontents{customchapter}
    [0pt]   % left-indent; change as you see fit
    {% above-code
        \medbreak % for example
        \large\bfseries
        \color{green}%
    }{% numbered-entry-format
        \def\numberline##1{% >>> CRUDE HACK <<<
            \customchaptername~##1:\hspace{1em}%
        }%
    }{%numberless-entry-format
        % leave empty
    }{% page-format
        \hfill\contentspage
    }



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Inferno}

\chapter{Prologo}
Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita mi ritrovai per una selva oscura, ch\'{e} 
la diritta via era smarrita.

\chapter{Dubbi di Dante}
Lo giorno se ne andava, e l'aere bruno toglieva gli animai che sono in terra 
dalle fatiche loro.

\customchapter{Il primo capitolo jolly}
Dovrebbe cominciare la numerazione da~<<A>>.

\chapter{Ingresso all'Inferno}
Per me si va nella citt\`{a} dolente, per me si va nell'etterno dolore, per me 
si va tra la perduta gente.
\section{Ignavi}
Non ragioniam di lor, ma guarda e passa.
\section{Caronte}
Ed ecco verso noi venir per nave un vecchio, bianco per antico pelo, gridando 
<<Guai a voi, anime prave!>>

\customchapter{Un altro capitolo jolly}
Deve essere numerato~<<B>>.

\chapter{Limbo}
Ruppemi l'alto sonno nella testa un greve truono, s\'{\i} ch'io mi riscossi,
come persona ch'\`{e} per forza desta.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems your crude hacke works great. Now I have to make more complicated. On ToC I need this format for the entry: `\customchaptername~\thecustomchapter: My Title`. I don't know how to manage this with `titletoc`.

Comment: @AlbertoVerdoja: Does the edited code do what you want?

Comment: Yes, but now I have to style my ToC. And I'm figuring out how to do with `titletoc`.

For Part (and custom chapter) I need to write just `\partname~\Alph{\thepart}`, and for chapters just `\chaptername~\thechapter: The Chapter Title`

Comment: @AlbertoVerdoja: why `\Alph{part}`?  (I guess `\Alph{\thepart}` is an oversight.)

Comment: Maybe I was wrong, what I need is just: `Parte 1` and `Custom Chapter A: The custom chapter title` :D

Comment: @AlbertoVerdoja: See if it now is OK.  Note the slight imperfection in the hyperlinks for parts, though.